# Console app timer to call web methods every x minutes

Tags: vb.net, timer, console

I am coding in VB.Net, VS 2008. 
I wrote a console app that consumes 2 web methods from a web site application.  I need to enhance this console app so that it launches the web methods continuously, perhaps every x minutes (during business hours), but never before the last invocation has terminated, whose duration may vary, depending on how many accounts there are to process.

Originally, I scheduled the application using Task Scheduler, but I think this doesn't prevent two invocations at the same time.

Although I have seen many posts on using timers, I haven't found exactly what I need.

So far I have:

```
Dim aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer()
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf TriggerWebMethods

' Set the Interval to 10 minutes:
aTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 10            '(1 second * 60 = 1 minute * 10 = 10 minutes)
aTimer.Enabled = True
aTimer.AutoReset = True
```

1. When should `Timer.Elapsed` be used vs. `Timer.Tick`?
2. What is the difference between `Timer.Enabled` vs `Timer.Start`, and should I be selecting just one?
3. I would like the 2nd web method to kick off when the first one is done.

I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.  Thank you for all help.

Comment: What does your `TriggerWebMethods()` method look like?

Comment: The whole process is fairly complex: data is being transferred from the db on one server to the db on another, encrypted, and then, asynchronously, transferred to a destination server, where it is decrypted. New data will become  available for transmission throughout the day.  So TriggerWebMethods contains a call to each web reference, followed by logging the time to the Event Log.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer has a Elapsed-Event and System.Windows.Forms.Timer has a Tick-Event. Have a look at this link to see the differences: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2122

Comment: Any reason why you're not doing this as a Windows Service?

Comment: @Conrad: No reason re Windows Service. I only first heard of Windows Services yesterday when I started researching this, so I don't know much about them.

Comment: Well if you had you did use windows events you get a well understood way (by the user) of running an application in the background that has a lot of support. Using a console app is a bit easier to write and run but you'll be missing all of the other support management options (too many options to list in a comment)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a `System.Timers.Timer`, then you'd only have the `Elapsed` event available.  If a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, then you'd use the `Tick` event.  You're not writing a WinForms app so you would be using the `System.Timers.Timer`.

Personally, I would only use the `Enabled` property to see if the timer has been started.  I wouldn't use it to start or stop it.  Using the `Start()` or `Stop()` method makes it very clear what's happening to the timer.

If your web methods execute synchronously, you could just call them one after the other in your `TriggerWebMethods()` method.  The second will not be called until the first completes.

```
Sub TriggerWebMethods(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    FirstWebMethod()
    SecondWebMethod()
End Sub
```

If asynchronously, you'd have to register a callback on the first web method to execute the second when it completes.  In VB, I believe you can use the second directly as the callback, depending on how you make the asynchronous call.  (Sorry, my VB is very rusty now so might not be 100% correct syntax)

```
Sub FirstWebMethod()
    ' ...
End Sub

Sub SecondWebMethod()
    ' ...
End Sub

Sub TriggerWebMethods(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    Dim first As Action = AddressOf FirstWebMethod
    first.BeginInvoke(AddressOf SecondWebMethod, first)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! What's a Callback? If it's too complicated to explain here, can you provide a link?  The code I currently have does not seem to call the web methods at all.  I have a breakpoint on TriggerWebMethods but the execution doesn't get there.

Comment: @Developer: A callback is just some method to be called when the asynchronous call completes.  In your case, when the first method call completes, you want to call the second.

Comment: All: I need some more help. My web method is not being called, as far as I can see. I have the web app launched from VS, and I have a breakpoint established on the entry point of the first web method. I launch the console app (also from the IDE) and watch it execute a few lines of code and then apparently stop. Do and of you guys have a few more minutes to help? Thank you.

Comment: @Developer: Could you update your question to include how you call your web methods and mark where you say it stops?  We'd need a bit more information.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Would've done it earlier but I was out of votes (stupid electorate badge and its 25% question requirement.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little to Jeff M's answer. The [Timer.Elapsed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) has the following note.

> If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is
>   raised on a ThreadPool thread. If the
>   processing of the Elapsed **event lasts**
>    **longer than Interval**, the event might
>   be raised again on another ThreadPool
>   thread. In this situation, the event
>   handler should be **reentrant**.

Since you're in a Console app you can either hand roll you own SynchronizingObject or you can set the `AutoReset` to `False`, and change your TriggerWebMethods to have a start at the end. You may even want to offset the interval to take into consideration the amount of processing time.

e.g.

```
    Dim start As Date = Now


    'do stuff


    Dim ts As TimeSpan = Now - start

    Dim i As Integer = (1000 * 60 * 10) - ts.TotalMilliseconds

    Dim aTimer As Timers
    aTimer.Interval = i
```

Comment: Conrad and Jeff, thank you for taking the time to respond. But I seem to be going backwards. I can't get the web method call to trigger at all now.  I have seen some examples where someone coded WithEvents when instantiating the Timer. What's the difference in these 2 approaches?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2208775/119477 for the WithEvents bit. Not sure why your event isn't being triggered. What does your AddHandler look like?