# Garbage collection of C# object declared in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, garbage-collection

In the following code, I create a DispatcherTimer in the class's constructor. No one keeps reference on it.

In my understanding, the timer should be reclaimed by the garbage collector some time after leaving the constructor's scope. 
But that doesn't happen! Even after forcing a garbage collection with `GC.Collect()`

What is going on under the hood?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            IsEnabled = true
        }
        .Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            textBlock1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you just construct the a `DispatcherTimer`, nothing prevents it from be GCed. However, you set `IsEnabled = true`, which will call `Start()` on the timer. When that, happens, this line of code will be executed:

```
this._dispatcher.AddTimer(this);
```

And now the `Dispatcher` itself is rooting the timer, meaning it can't be GCed.

Answer (score 4):

Timers are rather special since they root themselves by calling

```
this.timerRoot = GCHandle.Alloc(this);
```

some links

- [Timer, event and garbage collection : am I missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311027/timer-event-and-garbage-collection-am-i-missing-something/2311184#2311184)
- [Event handler and memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207541/eventhandler-and-memory-leaks/2207633#2207633)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/05/05/memory-leak-via-event-handlers.aspx

**EDIT:**

Didn't realize that it was a `DispatcherTimer` - that doesn't root itself directly but indirectly (to the `Dispatcher`) which in turn leads to the same effect...

Comment: Are DispatcherTimers subject to the same garbage collection rules as Threading.Timers? If so, not having a field reference (only a local reference) to the timer would cause garbage collection in and of itself...but I don't think that's the case with DispatcherTimers...

Comment: @JeffN825 All objects are subject to the same GC rules: if you're unreachable from a GC root, then you're eligible for GC. In this case, that code isn't even *from* the correct timer class.

Comment: @dlev just didn't realize it was a DispatcherTimer - see my EDIT

Comment: My point was that a locally scoped Threading.Timer with just a local reference is NOT rooted....and thus will be GC'd without ever ticking.

Comment: @JeffN825 that is not always true... since a Timer could "root itself" directly or indirectly... I didn't examine the Threading.Timer source (via Reflector) to be sure but AFAIK it calls internally TimerBase.AddTimer which seems to create a reference even for locally scoped Timers... so it too could very well be "rooted indirectly" in your scenario...

Comment: I don't believe that's correct. Have a read on the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: Now that is something different than the Threading.Timer you refered to at first... although I am inclined to check System.Timers.Timer with Reflector... in Reflector you can see that it internally uses Threading.Timer (at least in .NET 4)... so all bets are off...

Answer (score 1):

It will be added to the `Dispatcher` queue which will be rooted.